# How do I access the JSON from calling Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: json, powershell, curl

I need to call an API (to get a list of records from my DNS provider), and that can be done using curl.  This returns formatted json with all of my records

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer mytoken' -H 'Accept: application/json' https://api.dnsimple.com/v2/12345/zones/example.com/records
```

However, I need to be able to do this from PowerShell

```
$uri = "https://api.dnsimple.com/v2/12345/zones/example.com/records"
$headers = @{}
$headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer mytoken"
$headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
$foo = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Headers $headers
```

This command runs, but where in **$foo** can I access the returned JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `Invoke-WebRequest`, you would access the Content property: `$foo.Content`

Note that you can also use `Invoke-RestMethod`, which automatically converts JSON responses to PowerShell objects.

So this:

```
$o = Invoke-RestMethod #params
```

Would be the same as this:

```
$foo = Invoke-WebRequest #params
$o = $foo.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
```